# How to tweak Tape Equilibrium assignment on Codility to be of complexity O(N)?

Tags: java, algorithm, complexity

Why Codility detects [my solution for Tape Equilibrium](https://codility.com/demo/results/training7VX7GC-TDN/) to have complexity of \$O(n^2)\$. How can I make my code better?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        boolean eachIntegerIsWithinValidRange = IntStream.of(A).allMatch(i -> (i >= -1000 && i <= 1000));
        boolean numberOfElementsIsWithinDesignatedBounds = A.length >= 2 && A.length <= 100000;

        if (numberOfElementsIsWithinDesignatedBounds && eachIntegerIsWithinValidRange) {
            List<Integer> differences = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            if (A.length < 3) {
                Arrays.sort(A);
                return A[0];
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < A.length - 1; j++) {
                int[] subArrayOne = Arrays.copyOfRange(A, 0, j + 1);
                int[] subArrayTwo = Arrays.copyOfRange(A, j + 1, A.length);
                int sumOne = IntStream.of(subArrayOne).sum();
                int sumTwo = IntStream.of(subArrayTwo).sum();

                differences.add(Math.abs(sumOne - sumTwo));
            }
            Collections.sort(differences, (o1, o2) -> o1.compareTo(o2));
            return differences.get(0);
        } else if (!eachIntegerIsWithinValidRange) {
            throw new RuntimeException("There is/are integer that is out of designated bound: -1000 to 1000");
        } else if (!numberOfElementsIsWithinDesignatedBounds) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid array size. Allowed number of elements is more than 1 and less than 100,001");
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some interesting answers.

Answer (score 7):

#### General improvements

- Your method can be made `static`
- Your variable name `A` would be better as `input`
- By using "early return" or "early throw", your intendation level can be improved a bit
- `Collections.sort(differences, (o1, o2) -> o1.compareTo(o2));` can be just `Collections.sort(differences);`
- You are using `A.length < 3` as an edge case, I would just consider `A.length <= 1` as an edge case, the rest should be possible to be handled by your algorithm.

#### Why is your approach \$O(n^2)\$?

Consider what this code is actually doing:

```
for (int j = 0; j < A.length - 1; j++) {
    int[] subArrayOne = Arrays.copyOfRange(A, 0, j + 1);
    int[] subArrayTwo = Arrays.copyOfRange(A, j + 1, A.length);
    int sumOne = IntStream.of(subArrayOne).sum();
    int sumTwo = IntStream.of(subArrayTwo).sum();

    differences.add(Math.abs(sumOne - sumTwo));
}
Collections.sort(differences, (o1, o2) -> o1.compareTo(o2));
```

For every index in your array it does the following things:

- Create an subarray, which is an \$O(n)\$ operation
- Calculate the sum of the two newly created arrays, which is an \$O(n)\$ operation

These operations makes your code become \$O(n^2)\$

Additionally, it then afterwards does a `Collections.sort` operation which is \$O(n * log(n))\$

#### How to do it faster

- Initialize a variable `sum` to be the sum of your whole array, and a `sum2` to be 0
- For every index, decrease `sum` with the current value, and increase `sum2` with the current value. Then create a diff for `sum` and `sum2` and see if it is lower than the previous lowest record.

**Spoiler alert: Here is what I ended up with.**

```
public static int solution(int[] input) {
    boolean eachIntegerIsWithinValidRange = IntStream.of(input).allMatch(i -> (i >= -1000 && i <= 1000));
    boolean numberOfElementsIsWithinDesignatedBounds = input.length >= 2 && input.length <= 100000;

    if (!eachIntegerIsWithinValidRange) {
        throw new RuntimeException("There is/are integer that is out of designated bound: -1000 to 1000");
    }
    if (!numberOfElementsIsWithinDesignatedBounds) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid array size. Allowed number of elements is more than 1 and less than 100,001");
    }
    if (input.length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    int sum = IntStream.of(input).sum() - input[0];
    int sum2 = input[0];
    int lowestDiff = Math.abs(sum - sum2);
    for (int j = 1; j < input.length - 1; j++) {
        int value = input[j];
        sum -= value;
        sum2 += value;
        int diff = Math.abs(sum - sum2);
        if (diff < lowestDiff) {
            lowestDiff = diff;
        } else {
            return lowestDiff; // diff will not get any lower
        }
    }
    return lowestDiff;
}
```

Comment: Codility calculated 25% out of 100% for your code. Am I missing something?  https://codility.com/demo/results/trainingKKE2HC-F7V/

Comment: @RCola That means there's a bug in my code. It says on the link there: *For example, for the input [-1000, 1000] the solution returned a wrong answer (got 0 expected 2000).* Maybe it is I who haven't fully understood the requirements yet.

Comment: @RCola Edited my code to fix the problem. Although I would recommend that you pay more attention to the other parts of my answer instead of my resulting code.